# Kivy accessibility for screen readers

Tags: accessibility, kivy, screen-readers

I'm just learning Kivy and before I go any further I would like to know if there are any code examples that show how to make Kivy apps accessibile to screen reader users. For example, proving alternative text that says when an accordion is open or close, alternative text for images, alternative text for button that opens menus, etc.

thanks

Comment: If I'm right, there are no such examples in kivy for now. At least not directly in kivy(github repo). But maybe you can implement it (or at least something similar) with TTS and/or custom keyboard events.